# Contact Form 7 Database get_current_user_id show 0

Tags: php, wordpress

hello I added a new field to the Contact Form 7 Database plugin when i want to fill it is strange because i can not fill it with get_current_user_id

code: contact-form-cfdb-7.php

```
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

$cfdb->insert($table_name, array(
     'form_post_id' => $form_post_id,
     'form_user_id' => $current_user_id,
     'form_value'   => $form_value,
     'form_date'    => $form_date
));
```

im logged as admin and get_current_user_id registred as 0 !!!
HERE IMAGE:

[image]

Comment: I should var_dump $current_user_id to check it contains what you expect. Are the other columns being populated correctly?